# How can I place an external axis guide in a 3D (pgfplots) plot?

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I'm sure there's a term for this decoration, but I'm failing to come up with it. I'd like to create a 3D plot with PGFplots, but I want an axis legend (x/y/z unit vectors) placed outside the plot to guide the reader. I'm actually having a lot of trouble finding an example of this online, so pardon the poor quality scan. Is there a way to create this within PGF plots (so that it rotates with the rest of the plot when I apply rotation transforms)?

[image: 3D plot with an external axis in the lower left corner]

Comment: You mean the three arrows that don't sit at the origin? Just an idea: Why not just draw the plot without any visible axes and add the arrows manually (by placing three arrows that point into the 3 dimensions from, say, the coordinate `(0,0,-2)`)? PGFPlots provides for an `axis [x|y|z] line shift` option, which might also helpful.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, I'm looking to reproduce the above figure, and the box planes are a helpful part of the visualization, so the `axis line shift` option doesn't work in this case. However, just doing a `\draw` command for the vectors does solve the problem, just requires some tweaking on my part to get the right spacing. While I was hoping for an automated option, this is a perfectly functional solution. If you want to make it an answer, I'll mark it accepted in a day or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about your plot, since you did not provide any code. But the easiest way to achieve this would probably be to just manually draw the three arrows outside the actual plot using something like the following:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[clip=false]
        \addplot3 coordinates { (0,0,0) (1,0,0) };

        \coordinate (axis line origin) at (0,-2.5,-1);
        \draw[->] (axis line origin) -- +(0.15,0,0) node[right] (axis line x label) {$X_B$};
        \draw[->] (axis line origin) -- +(0,0.5,0) node[right] {$T$};
        \draw[->] (axis line origin) -- +(0,0,0.5) node[right] {$p$}; 
        \node[below, font=\small, inner sep=5pt] at (axis line x label) {($X_{BL}$ or $X_{BV}$)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]